# Daylight savings time in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, time

We're using an old application that stores dates in C / Unix format. C time is basically the number of seconds since Jan 1st, 1970.  The dates are stored as an integer in a SQL Server database. I am writing a view for a report that uses these dates.

So far, I'm converting from the UNIX time to a native datetime with:

```
DateAdd(s,3600+unix_time,'1/1/1970')
```

The 3600 is to convert from UTC to our local GMT+1 timezone.  This is accurate in the winter, but in the summer it's one hour off due to daylight savings time.

Is there a built-in way to convert from UTC to local time in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of 3600, you'll want to do DateDiff(s, getutcdate(), getdate())+unix_time, which will give you the correct offset from the UTC time.

Cheers,
Eric

Comment: Thanks!  Had to change the order (getdateutc() first) but after that it works fine.

Comment: Fantastic.  I fixed the code in my post.  It's a little too early for me to be getting syntax right here in my time zone :)

Comment: This doesnt work with regions that observe daylight savings time.

Comment: I don't understand how this can be the correct answer. It will adjust the time by the _current_ time zone offset - so if run in winter it might adjust all times by one hour, but when run in the summer, it would adjust all times by two hours (or whatever your particular offsets are). It doesn't take the stored time into accound.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, the answer above neglects daylight savings time. If it's not currently daylight savings time a date within a daylight savings period will be an hour off and vice-versa. Also, lawmakers in many different countries love to make daylight savings more complicated than it needs to be.

Essentially, try to avoid this in SQL Server if at all possible. Client side date handling libraries can usually get it about right. If you need to work with timestamps already in the database, consider converting them to datetime columns or converting date values into timestamps in client code before using them as query parameters.

This is just one of those wheels that consistently gets invented the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with UTC/GMT1, and while the many statements that this is something you want to avoid in the database are very true and valueable advice, it is not always possible to avoid this entirely.

However, when you are working with GMT1 you are in luck since the daylight savings for this is actually based on an algorithm. (unlike US daylight savings which I understand is decided by legislative bodies.)

From this I was able to make this stored procedure that converts UTC datetime input to GMT1 datetime. Hope this helps ;)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spUTCGMT1 @date AS DATETIME
AS 
BEGIN
     DECLARE @year AS INT = DATEPART( YYYY,@date)
     DECLARE @f AS INT = (FlOOR( (5 * @year) / 4) - FLOOR( @year / 100)+ FLOOR( @year / 400)) % 7

     IF(@date BETWEEN 
        DATEADD( DD,- ((@f + 5) % 7),(CAST(@year AS CHAR(4)) + '-03-31')) AND 
        DATEADD( DD,- ((@f + 2) % 7),(CAST(@year AS CHAR(4)) + '-10-31')))
     SELECT 
            DATEADD( HH,2,@date)
     ELSE
     SELECT 
            DATEADD( HH,1,@date)
END
```