# Calculate daylight saving info using datetime offset in UTC with SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to calculate daylight saving info using datetime offset in UTC with SQL Server 2008?

I.e I need daylight saving aware datetime offset data type in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this?  I realize the unix part may not apply, but the formula might.
[Daylight savings time in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796723/daylight-savings-time-in-sql-server)

And then there's this:  http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1372